# Android, Java - Fix an OCR-ed word to a valid english dictionary word in real time

Tags: java, android, performance, ocr, levenshtein-distance

My application involves scanning through the phone camera and detecting text. The only words that my application is concerned with is valid english words.
I have a list of ~354,000 valid english words that i can compare my scanned word with.

Since my application continuously detects text, i need this functionality to be very very fast. I have applied Levenshtein Distance technique. For each word, I:

1. Store the contents of the text file into an `Arraylist<String>` using `Scanner`
2. Calculate Levenshtein Distance of the word with each  of the 354k words
3. Return the word corresponding to the minimum distance value

The problem is that it is very very slow. Without applying this, my app manages to ocr more than 20 words in around 70 to 100 millisecond. When i include this fixing routine, my app takes more that 1 full minute (60000ms) for a single word.

I was wondering if this technique is even suitable, given my case. If not, what other tested way should i go with? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know this is possible, looking at how android keyboards are able to instantly correct our incorrectly typed words.

Other Failed endeavors:

- Jaro distance. (similar)
- Android internal `SpellCheckerSession` service. (doesn't fit my case. Result receipt via a callback is the issue)

Comment: @Andy cutting down the list is not an option unfortunately. May there be any hashing or mapping technique that i could incorporate here?

Comment: I'm not necessarily meaning "cutting down the list" as in completely discarding words; I mean that you need a way to partition the list such that you don't search words which it is impossible to match. For instance, I presume that you have some idea about how long the word will be - can you check only words of that length +/- 1, say?

Comment: @Andy Say even if i somehow narrow down the words list to one tenth, that still means 6 seconds per word. Whereas, smartphone keyboards are able to do it instantly. I would really like to know about that technique

Comment: It's a step in the right direction, isn't it?

Comment: @AndyTurner, unfortunately in the context of OCR, it is a no go. OCR can get a character wrong. Additionally, they can totally miss a character in the sense that if 'I' is recognized as '1', i will have already removed numbers from the recognizeds words. Hence M1ster -> Mster -> will not consider Mister ever

Comment: You can't make a computer work faster; you can only have it do less stuff it doesn't need to. Unless you can make your distance calculation orders of magnitude faster, you've simply got to make it check fewer strings, by some means.

Comment: @AndyTurner I totally understand. I do however strongly suspect there there is a whole other technique out there that would fit here better than the 'minimum edit distance' method. Would you by any chance know of some alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution that works:
I created a MYSQL table and uploaded the list of valid english words in it. It solves all the problems addressed in the question.

Here is my Android Application for reference:
[Optical Dictionary & Vocabulary Teacher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abdulwasaetariq.odnvt)